# Node CORS fine on Chrome but not Safari / Firefox

Tags: node.js, vue.js, cors

Loggin into my app is fine on chrome but not on Safari & Firefox.

On Safari I get the following: [image]

and on Firefox I get the following: [image]

On Chrome all is good.

In my app.js I have the following:

```
app.use(cors({
    'allowedHeaders': ['sessionId', 'Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'authorization'],
    'exposedHeaders': ['sessionId'],
    'origin': 'https://www.eccentrictoad.com',
    // 'origin': 'http://localhost:8080',
    'methods': 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    'credentials': false,
    'preflightContinue': false
  }));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

const progressRoutes = require("./routes/progressRoutes");
const progressResultsRoutes = require("./routes/progressResultRoutes");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes");
app.use(progressRoutes, progressResultsRoutes, userRoutes);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(chalk.bold.red(`Wayne's App listening on port: ${port}`));
});
```

My login route is as follows:

```
router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  let user_password = req.body.password;
  let hashedPassword = "";
  let mysql = `select * from users where userEmail = '${req.body.email}'`;
  console.log(chalk.yellow(mysql));
  pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    if (err) {
      connection.release();
      res.json({ error: "Error with connection. Are you online?" });
    }
    connection.query(mysql, function (error, result) {
      if (error) {
        res.json({ error: "No such user" });
      } else {
        if (!result.length) {
          res.json({
            error: `No user registered under "${req.body.email}", try signup and register as a user.`,
          });
        } else {
          console.log(result)
          let hash = result[0].userPassword;
          let userJson = {
            id: result[0].id,
            userEmail: result[0].userEmail,
            userName: result[0].userName,
            userRole: result[0].userRole,
            userMobile: result[0].userMobile
          };
          bcrypt.compare(user_password, hash, function (err, response) {
            if (response) {
              res.json({
                user: userJson,
                token: jwtSignUser(userJson),
              });
            } else {
              res.json({
                error: "Password is incorrect. Please try again",
              });
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
    connection.release();
  });
});
```

Searched everywhere but cannot find the answer.

Do I need to put cors in the individual router files as well?

Comment: @goto1 - mytoad.co.za is the server? eccentrictoad.com is the client. That is where the login call is coming from.

Comment: The Safari error suggests that you're using `https://eccentrictoad.com`, without the `www`. The config has the `www`. Also, take a look at the headers that are coming back from the server to see what they are.

Comment: @skirtle - Thank you, that was spot on. When I type in www then all good. I guess I should put both with and without www  in my cors??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two origins involved here, `https://eccentrictoad.com` and `https://www.eccentrictoad.com`. To allow requests from both you can use an array for the `origin` configuration option:

```js
'origin': ['https://eccentrictoad.com', 'https://www.eccentrictoad.com'],
```

From a CORS perspective these count as totally separate origins, even if they're actually the same server.